# How to get ACF Post Object to only show 1 post?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF Post Object field where a user can select 1 post. I am following the instructions here - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

I want to use setup_postdata so I can use Wordpress template functions, so I am using this code -

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('featured_posts');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

        // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and in my 'featured_posts' field on that page I have 1 article selected.

But when I use that code it shows all the posts, not just the single one that is selected.

How can I get it to only show the article that is selected?

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($featured_posts)`?  Are there multiple posts?

Comment: It could be that you are not passing the post id to get_field, as in get_field('featured_posts', $post_id); You need to get $post_id first of course. Where are you adding this code exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use foreach, declare the variable of the field like $post.

Like this:

```
<?php
$case1 = get_field('case1');
if( $case1 ): ?>
                    
<?php 
$post = $case1;
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li>...
```